# Kinesis Lambda Source Transformation: data attribute not base64 encoded

Tags: node.js, lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a log stream in Kinesis that I am trying to transform before it's sent out to our log monitoring service. The data being sent is a JSON array, I want to pull the single object out of the array and send this object to the log monitoring service.

The [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/) says that the log data is base64 encoded, but my efforts to decode it have failed.

The code below is what I'm using to transform the data.

```
const parseData = (data) => {
 
  // Attempt to base64 decode the data

  // This doesn't decode the string into recognisable characters.
  const dataString = dataString = Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii')
  
  // Attempt to parse the base64 decoded data as JSON
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(dataString)[0]
  
  return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(parsedData)).toString('base64')
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const output = event.records.map((record) => ({
        recordId: record.recordId,
        result: 'Ok',
        data: parseData(record),
    }));
    console.log(`Processing completed.  Successful records ${output.length}.`);
    return { records: output };
};
```

An example `event.record`:

```
{ 
  recordId: '...', 
  approximateArrivalTimestamp: 123, 
  data: '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', 
  kinesisRecordMetadata: { 
    sequenceNumber: '...', 
    subsequenceNumber: 0, 
    partitionKey: '...', 
    shardId: '...', 
    approximateArrivalTimestamp: 123 
  } 
}
```

When I attempt to base64 decode the above `data` value with the code below, I get garbled output:

```
const data = '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'

console.log(Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii'))
```

Output:

```
TDH+~;c&!P@Jarfc=yoOd'mic61
          2
N9IQtT|9**E5B|j]ZQNpc_1ZNv      gZ-ETV`kE
'1fP^LjU0 6S!/X#xkN!bB-UA
F;"x,l 6VaaCf
             ?=o1       {-5 ZX`bW~DCtZ1\ vT%c("."i5Z!JqV@Ztm)B a,/sb!3(PJ#?I'+p_/+_%|8Kf9HAH+&ZcomrLZN%6PS4F<8#[B/n^G_1-,WxS>   $b87y|~:o{>y~VIw8nFzpw2.q$56_>M9)dDouFR3g4#N
                                        fM0lC$Qj%"\g'~AcI=$16}8\~7%bN
                                                                     c'^PO0
                                                                           N#_6qG_/Sx}VYk}keSTuVUGkrlN37}1KGE=`u"L77=7MiR]gl0.
][
```

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way I'm supposed to be decoding these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data was compressed. A working example:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const data = 'H4s... etc';
const compressed = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
const decompressed = zlib.unzipSync(compressed);
console.log(decompressed.toString());
```